# VSCode IntelliSense autocomplete suddenly stopped working with node modules

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense

I'm trying to make a steam bot with JS, and IntelliSense does not work.

[image: intellisense not working]

I have my `SteamUser` object declared:

```js
const SteamUser = require("steam-user");
const client = new SteamUser()
```

It recognizes the `logOn` function:

[image: logOn function showing params]

But IntelliSense doesn't work. I tried restarting VSCode, entering command pallete and using the `Developer: Reload Window` command, but to no avail.

In a discord.js project IntelliSense also doesn't work:

[image: intellisense not working in a discord.js project]

I have run `npm install`:

[image: npm packages up to date]

Here is my `package.json`:

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "steam-user": "^5.0.1"
  }
}
```

EDIT: Just found out that local `require`s also don't work.

Example:

```js
const config = require("./config.json")
```

[image: no autocomplete on config object]

`config.json`:

```json
{
    "accountName": "something",
    "password": "something2"
}
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541

Comment: @starball sure, but the images demonstrate how vscode doesn't show intellisense function suggestions

Comment: I'm not talking about _all_ of your images- just one of them (now).

Comment: Check if the file you are trying to import exists in node_modules

Comment: Check if intellisense works at all (for in project files)

Comment: Check if go-to-definition of those points somewhere

Comment: @Dimava intellisense works, file is in node_modules, goto doesnt point to anything

Comment: please elaborate on what you mean by "local requires don't work".

Answer (score 0):

[image]

`[DT]` mark on NPM means this package does not have builtin types
You need to additionally install `npm install --dev @types/steam-user` for the types to work
[image]

Comment: did not fix my problem